Does the Supremacy Clause allow states to retain abortion rights enshrined in each states' constitution?
In the upcoming election, several states intend to put abortion rights on the ballot for consideration by the voters with successful passage resulting in an amendment to that state's constitution which will preserve those rights.
Some candidates for Congress have indicated that if they are able to successfully take back both Congress and the Presidency, they would ban abortions on the federal level. For the sake of this argument, let's assume they have the votes to do so.
Presumably, the passage of a federal law to ban abortion nationwide would be in direct contradiction with state laws. However, if these various votes are successful this is a bit more than a state law, rather it's an amendment to a state's constitution. Would the passage of a federal abortion ban automatically repeal the various states' constitutional amendments? Or would they be considered void until such time that the federal law is repealed?
Could doctors in those states continue to perform abortions under the presumption that nobody in the state will enforce the federal law? This would be akin to how many states have legalized cannabis to a variety of degrees despite it continuing to be illegal on a federal level.

A federal statute overrides a state constitutional provision if the two are in conflict.

Isn’t this a duplicate of this? https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97442/could-a-federal-law-override-a-state-constitution

@SegNerd I think you're right.


Would the passage of a federal abortion ban automatically repeal the
various states' constitutional amendments? Or would they be considered
void until such time that the federal law is repealed?

They would be void until such time that the federal law is repealed (assuming, for sake of argument, that the federal ban is constitutional, which is a long, complicated, indeterminate, and unresolved legal question).
For example, state constitutional provisions imposing religious requirements to hold public office remained in state constitutions long after they were held to be unconstitutional under the First Amendment establishment clause. Some may even still be there now.
Similarly, when the Dobson decision overruling Roe v. Wade was decided, many state laws on abortion, including one in Arizona, took effect again, despite the fact that those laws had been without effect due to Roe v. Wade for about fifty years.
The Supremacy Clause, in general, makes no distinction between state constitutions and state statutes. This point is right in the express language of the Supremacy Clause itself, which says:

This Constitution, and the Laws of the United States which shall be
made in Pursuance thereof; and all Treaties made, or which shall be
made, under the Authority of the United States, shall be the supreme
Law of the Land; and the Judges in every State shall be bound thereby,
any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary notwithstanding.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'm curious to know what sort of "ban" you are envisioning that a) isn't a criminal statute (where state and Federal governments are separate jurisdictions and could be harmonized) and b) isn't an amendment (otherwise your Constitutional concerns aren't relevant).

@MichaelW See the discussion in chat.

"assuming, for sake of argument, that the federal ban is constitutional, which is a long, complicated, indeterminate, and unresolved legal question" Interstate commerce clause. People are going to other states to get abortions. That gives Congress the legal justification to pass a law regulating it on a federal level.

Roe vs Wade enshrined abortion rights in federal law to prevent state law from banning abortions.
It's ar from inconceivable that the reverse could also be possible, using a similar legal construct to create a federal law that overrides state laws and even state constitutions (e.g. the way Obamacare (ab)uses the interstate commerce clause to require health insurance).
A constitutional change requires so much unity within a state (let alone the federal constitution) that I don't foresee any change to the constitution, let alone on a hot topic item like abortion, from ever passing. And if it did it'd probably be challenged as an unconstitutional amendment instantly (whether it'd be an amendment allowing OR banning abortion).

Somehow 2 "f"s got dropped in your typing (second word second paragraph, third from last word). Too few characters for me to edit.

I'm having a hard time following your intent on this. Right now, it seems like you're implying that Roe was a federal law instead of a SCOTUS ruling and you're suggesting the only way to ban abortion nationwide would require a constitutional amendment rather than just the passage of a bill by Congress and signed off by the President to become federal law. My question is regarding whether federal laws passed by Congress and signed by the President can supersede elements of a state's constitution as these feel more foundational than individual state laws.
